# Why do password entries over ssh take so long?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian-squeeze

When I'm ssh'd into my server, any time I enter my password, there's a 40 second delay before the server responds.

This occurs when logging in, as well as whenever I run a command via `sudo`. The delay does not happen when I run `su` and enter my password however.

Using the `-v` flag for `ssh` doesn't show anything during this time. Looking at Wireshark, all traffic between the two machines stops while this is happening.

Any idea what's happening, or advice on how to investigate this?

The server is running Debian squeeze (6.0.4)

Edit: contents of /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:        compat
group:         compat
shadow:        compat

hosts:         files dns
networks:      files

protocols:     db files
services:      db files
ethers:        db files
rpc:           db files

netgroup:      nis
```

Edit 2: result of `mount`

```
/dev/simfs on / type simfs (rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the server?

Comment: What authentication backend is used on the server?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's a VPS, so I don't have physical access to it if that's what you mean. Any clues would have to be gathered over ssh. As for looking on the server over ssh, I don't really know where to start.

Comment: @Paul I don't know anything about authentication backends past what a few minutes of Googling yielded. I see that I have directories for `pam` and `ldap` under `/etc`. Does that tell you anything useful?

Comment: Well it is possible that you are using ldap for auth in the backend, but it is failing and falling back to `/etc/passwd` auth.  If you could [edit] and post your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` it would answer this.

Comment: @Paul I added the file you specified.

Comment: @Dean perfectly normal.  Is /home a network disk by chance?

Comment: @Paul I don't believe so. How could I confirm?

Comment: Just type `mount` at the prompt, it will show where everything is mounted

Comment: @Paul results added with edit.

Comment: in my experience usually this is some sort of dns issue and it is waiting for a timeout. You can turn off dns resolving in the sshd file i believe.

Comment: @Sirex That can cause it to take a long time to show the password prompt in the first place. I already made that change ;)

Comment: You might also want to try unix.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be an explanation that doesn't relate to nsswitch.conf, your passwd auth engine etc.

If "su - " is slow but "su" is not, or "sudo" is loading something (like a .bashrc) then it *could* be that there's something in your profile/rc environment that is causing the slowdown.  I've seen this behavior on systems where you connect in and for some reason your profile, or your login/ssh daemon, feels the urge to do a DNS lookup of some sort (eg reverse lookup the source IP) and it sits there like a lemon for 40 seconds.

Just a thought.

Comment: `su -` is instant, and I tried removing my .bashrc, .profile, etc. files with no luck. I'll look deeper into the rest of the login process when I have a free moment. Maybe I'll try creating a new user to narrow down the scope.